# how to add checkbox values in mysql database?

Tags: mysql

how to add checkbox values in mysql database?Please help I always get this error when I incorporate checkbox in my form. Does the data type have to be changed in mysql.

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check (TRANSPORT, X, Y) VALUES ('vsf', 'car', 'fa')' at line 1

Comment: 1. Please clarify what you are asking for. What is the table structure and what query are you trying to run against it? 2. You should go back and accept answers on your old questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a checkbox use a bool/tinyint(1) column. HTML checkboxes only return a value if they are checked. Here's what I usually do:

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$myCheckbox = isset($myCheckbox);
```